# How to fix error: Skipping import row, required category "Nintendo DS / DS Lite / DSi" does not exist

Tags: magento, dataflow

I am importing products via dataflow advance profile in magento 9.1.1 from a remote csv via ftp. I have created all the categories in magento but when I run the import I get the below error.

```
Skipping import row, required category "Nintendo DS / DS Lite / DSi" does not exist.
```

I have looked high and low but cant find why this error is comming up and not importing the products in its respective category, below is the xml script I am running.

Anyone have any clue how to fix this, my other imports work just fine except for this one.

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">ftp</var>
    <var name="host"><![CDATA[xx.xxx.x.xxx]]></var>
    <var name="port"><![CDATA[portNo]]></var>
    <var name="passive">true</var>
    <var name="user"><![CDATA[username]]></var>
    <var name="password"><![CDATA[password]]></var>
    <var name="path"><![CDATA[/]]></var>
    <!-- path to file on remote server-->
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[csv_q/mc-datafile_stock7.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="lanot_dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
<var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
<var name="enclose"><![CDATA[]]></var>
<var name="fieldnames">true</var>

<var name="map">
    <map name="Manufacture Reference"><![CDATA[sku]]></map>
    <map name="Product Name"><![CDATA[name]]></map>
    <map name="Long Description"><![CDATA[description]]></map>
    <map name="Trade Our Price"><![CDATA[cost]]></map>
    <map name="Trade RRP"><![CDATA[price]]></map>
    <map name="Ean Code"><![CDATA[ean]]></map>
    <map name="Brand"><![CDATA[manufacturer]]></map>
    <map name="Stock Level"><![CDATA[qty]]></map>
    <map name="Weight"><![CDATA[weight]]></map>
    <map name="Dimensions"><![CDATA[dimensions]]></map>
    <map name="Category Name"><![CDATA[category_ids]]></map>
    <map name="Sub-Category Name"><![CDATA[category_ids]]></map>
    <map name="Image Names (Comma Separated)"><![CDATA[image]]></map>

    <map name="@type"><![CDATA[simple]]></map>
    <map name="@attribute_set"><![CDATA[Default]]></map>
    <map name="@visibility"><![CDATA[Catalog, Search]]></map>
    <map name="@status"><![CDATA[Enabled]]></map>
    <map name="@tax_class_id">Taxable Goods</map>
    <map name="@websites">base</map>
</var>

    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter"><![CDATA[catalog/convert_adapter_product]]></var>
    <var name="method">parse</var>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend to you take a look into [MAGMI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/). This tool is much flexible and faster that the default Magento importer.

Comment: I am trying to test the understandingE version om magmi but I cant seem to find any information on how to use it, I have installed it but understandinge want us to pay to see their tutorials; do you have any links to free tutorials and the magmi wiki does not provide a enough info on mapping remote csv to import.